# The accepted answer is wrong

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

An answer has been marked as "Accepted" but is clearly wrong.
Is there anything that can be done about this?

This is the url:
[How to set a default font for outgoing messages in Mail on Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38320/how-to-set-a-default-font-for-outgoing-messages-in-mail-on-lion/38333#38333)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing can be done, although you can downvote the answer (and either answer with the correct answer, providing some reference to the accepted answer, or comment underneath the accepted answer).

Mods cannot override, remove, or nominate accepted answers, only the OP can do that.

Comment: In the specific case mentioned in the question, there are already comments indicating the fact that the answer is actually wrong.

Comment: Who marked this answer as correct?! ;)

Answer (score 6):

"Accepted" basically means that the asker was happy with the answer (which doesn't necessarily mean it's correct). Usually votes are a better indicator on answer quality/correctness because more eyeballs are involved. So if you run into such a situation you can

- downvote wrong answers (even if they are accepted)
- upvote correct answers (or provide the correct answer if it is missing)
- add a comment to the question (so the asker gets notified) or the wrongly accepted answer (referencing the asker with @xyz)